# How to set TLS version at request level?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, httpwebrequest, tls1.2

We have an application in .Net Framework 4.7 which hosts multiple API endpoints. The application is deployed in multiple servers (some of them are old) and TLS 1.2+ is not enforced from them. This is causing some of the server to set TLS as 1.1 and others to set it as 1.2+.

Everything was working fine until now as these endpoints were calling other APIs which did not require TLS 1.2. Now, one of the downstream APIs require TLS 1.2+ while rest of them may still be using 1.1. So, wanted to check if we can set TLS 1.2 for only one of the APIs calls instead of setting it at application level?

We tried this code

```
var originalSecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;
try
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    // Make API call
}
finally
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = originalSecurityProtocol;
}
```

But found that there could be an issue with the concurrent calls. Any other solution that we can try?

Comment: TLS is connection-level, not request-level (a single TLS connection will be used to service multiple requests to the same host). Your question should be retitled "How to set TLS version per-host?" - not per-request.

Comment: You can solve this by using a per-host `HttpClient` by constructing its inner `HttpClientHandler` with `HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols` set accordingly - this won't work for `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` of course, but provided you use _only_  suitably configured `HttpClient` instances you should be okay. (Don't forget about the various lifetime issues involved with `HttpClient` on .NET 4.x though, consider using `IHttpClientFactory` - but you'll need to hack around `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` if you want per-host settings).

Comment: "TLS 1.2+ is not enforced from them" then sort out the server. Leaving TLS1.2 off by default is a security risk. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 Do not mess around with `ServicePointManager` just sort out the operating system.